# Unicode characters can not display correctly on opends entry

Tags: php, unicode, ubuntu, opends

again have problem with opends

now i would like to save unicode in the opends directory its can saved but when i fetch the results unicode characters are not displaying as it is

thanks in advance 
roshan

Comment: Hmm, Im sorry, but I don't now the solution for this. The only thing that comes to my mind is different charset of the data from PHP (or other programing language) that are stored into another charset... So the unicode characters are messed up. What charset (encoding) does opends store the data in and what charste are You using while operating with data? Common problem could be defining headers with one charset while script itself is running in other charset and then there is opends with the third charset... I'd recommend finding this out and trying to make it the same...

Comment: thank you shadyyx for reply i ll check this out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDS like any LDAP directory server, requires that the directory strings are UTF-8 encoded.
This is part of the LDAP RFCs.
It is up to the client tools to do the conversion (if needed) from UTF-8 to the local character set (and reverse when sending to the Directory server).

Kind regards,

Ludovic Poitou

Product Manager for OpenDJ, open source LDAP directory services in Java

ForgeRock.

Comment: Hi  Poitou

thank you very much for your reply.. that means i can save and fetch the utf-8 characters from OPEN DS via php client tool right?